# Error Specific RoundCorners on Old Devices?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rounded-corners

I added round corners function extension inside UIView

it works perfectly on a new device like `iPhone XR` but the old device with 16:9 ratio like `iPhone 8`,`iPhone 8 plus` it corners in just the left

```
extension UIView{
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

When I implement the function. inside the UIViewController, I call the function inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
//ViewController
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    exampleView.roundCorners([.topRight,.topLeft], radius: 20)
}
```

- but when I implement in class with another type I couldn't find a solution,
  I want a method to force take the corner always.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a view to always have cornerradius you can use following snippet:

```
@IBDesignable extension UIView{
@IBInspectable var cornerRadius : CGFloat{
    get{
        return self.layer.cornerRadius
    }set{
       layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
  }
}
```

You can set the radius in the InterfaceBuilder or in code.